# How to evaluate a hurdle model

Tags: machine-learning, classification, regression

Should the two sequential parts of a hurdle model (Response model and Expected value model) be tuned and evaluated independently, and then combines for the final results (Product of the probability to respond and the expected value)? Or should they be tuned and evaluated as a single model? What is the best approach to evaluated the overall/global performance of a two part hurdle model?

For example, if the two models are evaluated and tuned **independently**, then the hurdle model (i.e. probability to respond) will be evaluated based on classification metrics (e.g., ROC, F1, Recall, etc.) and the expected value model will be evaluated based on regression metrics (e.g., MSE, MAE, etc.). Once they combined, what is the best approach to evaluated the overall/global model performance?
Otherwise, if the two parts of the model should be combined in a **single** model to be tuned and evaluated, then can regression evaluated metrics be used to evaluated the overall/global model performance?

Comment: Are you looking for a causal or predictive model?

Comment: A predictive model. By causal, do you mean uplift model